# I created a product on my spare time from a customer's request that was ignored by my superior. Can I sell this?

Tags: software-industry

A customer come with a request a month back that we develop a solution for a specific part of his workflow. My manager denied, I asked him whether I could develop this on work hours so that we can sell it as it seemed a rather profitable asset. He denied again.

On my spare time and in order to learn my job better (software development) I developed and tested the product. It looks good. Now I want to sell this, not to the customer that made the request, but to general public.

Is this wrong? I do not want to notify my manager about my creation of this product.

Comment: While your dedication to improving and satisfying a customer need is a nice thing, you went against a direct order from your manager, after you asked twice. It is fine that you used it to train, but do not think about selling it, unless you want a very angry boss.

Comment: @Thalantas I don't see how he disobeyed his boss as long as it was his spare time and his private resources.

Comment: Did you develop the product with your own equipment or did you use work facilities?

Comment: Some people come up with ideas like this only after they leave their employ, yet manage to complete their development fairly quickly. Non-compete clauses can come into play, of course.

Comment: "*Is this wrong?*" Ethically or legally? The latter is off-topic here.

Comment: Why not sell it to the customer?

Comment: In case of a lawsuit: The fact that you asked twice and your company didn't want the product would be in your favour. They would find it very hard to claim damages, for example. If there is a non-compete agreement, the fact that they refused the product makes it clear that you are not competing.

Comment: The cheap and easy way is to ask your employer for permission. Once you receive permission in writing - from someone who has the authority to do so - there's no need for any lawyer. Doing this behind the back of your manager is unethical and does jeopardize your job, regardless if it's legal or not.

Answer (score 12):

**Check your contract**

It may differ where you're from, but I've seen many employment contracts for developers either claiming ownership of anything they develop, even outside of work hours, or forbidding them from competing with the company even after they leave that company's employment.

If it is a product which could be seen to be competing with your company then it is worth seeking local legal advice.

Comment: How would any developer sign a contract giving the employer ownership of projects done outside working hours? That seems crazy to me :o

Comment: @ThiefMaster because some contracts say that even if it's did on your own time it's theirs.

Comment: The good thing about contracts, however, is that they are also subject to the law. So, even if that's what the contract says - you should still discuss with a lawyer to discover whether it's enforceable. Of course, whether you should go up against your employer is a whole different question....

Comment: @Dan, very true—similarly, as I once saw pointed out on a different stack exchange, "Writing 'not liable for any damages' on your website doesn't automatically make you not liable for any damages."

Answer (score 5):

A lot of contracts include non-compete clauses, and intellectual property clauses. There's questions on Workplace SE in which developers ask for help with company contracts stating that *anything* they develop while employed is company property.

You need to read your employment contract very carefully, and determine what your own situation may be.

At the same time, you are essentially planning to compete against your employers. This is not going to go over well if they ever find out what you're doing.

If I were you, I would ask myself what it is you're trying to accomplish with this move.

If you simply wrote a one-off application, but have no plans to leave your job, then trying to make a few extra bucks at the cost of potentially being fired is probably not worth it. In fact, I would probably take the application to my boss, explain that I wrote it on my own time, and try to prove myself worthy of promotion, etc. (of course this all depends on the company's culture, your boss's attitude, etc.)

If, however, you think you could go into business selling this application, and making other systems like it, then perhaps you should save up some money over the next few months, quit, set up your own company, and start marketing your product.

It seems like a bad idea to try and compete with your employers behind their backs, however.

Comment: The OP is not competing against the employer if the product is not a sector of business that the employer is actively pursuing to be in, or already in.

Answer (score 3):

Have your lawyer review not only your employment contract but any other document you signed including NDAs - you probably developed your software from conversations with the customer that your employer might deem confidential - during the course of your employment. The whole of these documents assembled together as a set are more hazardous to your legal health than the sum of the documents i.e. the whole is more than dangerous to you than the sum of the parts, especially when the parts are interlocking.

You'll need a lawyer to sort this out because different locales have different laws regarding employment contracts, NDAs and the like and there might be a dispute as to the laws of which locale apply if you live in one locale, your office is in a second locale and your employer is headquartered in a third locale. And if you occasionally work remotely, it won't simplify matters, at least in my mind.

Besides, your lawyer is your advocate in a court of law while we at Stack Overflow don't take sides.